# How can I create dynamic labels using UIStackView

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift3, uistackview

I have 10 UILabels with different sizes, and I want to arrange them in 3 rows, and all rows have leading alignment, and if the last item of each row can't fit in remaining space of parent view, it have to move to the next line. How can I do that by using UIStackview?

[image: here's the image]

Comment: I'd recommend to use `UICollectionView` for that, it's much easier that way.

Comment: I agree with @the4kman, probably `UICollectionView` would be more appropriate to what are you trying to achieve.

Comment: @the4kman Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

You can try to do something like that:

Your ViewController

```
    for item in array {
        let someView = VPView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 70, height: 20))
        someView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        stackView.addArrangedSubview(someView)
    }
```

UIView Class:

```
class VPView: UIView {

    let myLabel = UILabel()

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        self.addLabel()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    func addLabels() {

        //Mark: - Styles
        let labelH: CGFloat = 15
        let labelW: CGFloat = 70

        //MARK: - My Label
        self.myLabel.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: labelW, height: labelH)
        self.myLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
        self.myLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.center
        self.myLabel.numberOfLines = 0
        self.addSubview(self.myLabel)

        self.myLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        self.myLabel.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: labelH).isActive = true
        self.myLabel.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: labelW).isActive = true
        self.myLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.topAnchor).isActive = true
        self.myLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leadingAnchor).isActive = true

    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but I think that this approach can't help me with moving items into next rows, because UIStackView just arrange them in one row.

Comment: You can create UIStackView for each line, but I think It's not a good approach. Try to use UICollectionView it's better.